# Why do I need "VISITING" state for nodes when performing a Breadth First Search?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I wrote an algorithm for searching in a graph and I used a flag to indicate whether a node was visited or not so I won't be stuck in a loop in case there is a circle in my graph.

I later checked an algorithm book which used 3 states instead of 2 the 3rd being the "VISITING" state. I was wondering why is it there since I can perform the search without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not strictly needed, but some algorithms which use BFS as a basic building block *use* this information, hence the extra state.

I guess from an educational viewpoint it's also a benefit, since the illustrations give a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I know that other algorithms use BFS. So there is no other reason for that state.

Comment: if you don't use it, you don't need it. does the algorithm you've read  actually use it?

Comment: Yes, it used it but it stated that "In fact[...]we would get the same result even if we did not distinguish between gray and black vertices." Gray means "visiting" black means "visited".

Answer (score 2):

A 'visiting' state doesn't make much sense - every node would be in this state only for the time you process its neighbors and enqueue them - and you know perfectly well which node you're visiting at the time.

What would make sense (but is still not needed) is a 'queued' state, such as the grey nodes in this animation (from wikipedia)

[image]